# How to preserve a formula's reference to a worksheet when the worksheet is deleted and replaced using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

How to keep formulas working after replacing a sheet?
I mean 
[How to preserve a formula's reference to a worksheet when the worksheet is deleted and replaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070930/how-to-preserve-a-formulas-reference-to-a-worksheet-when-the-worksheet-is-delet)
but in C#

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

 Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
 Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(connection.DataSource, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet sh in excelWorkbook.Sheets)
    {
        if (sh.Name == SheetName || sh.Name == "_"+SheetName)
        {
            sh.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
            sh.Delete();
        }
    }
    excelWorkbook.Save();
    excelWorkbook.Close(true, excelWorkbook.FullName, null);
    excelApp.Quit();
```

Later I'm invoking SQL command "Create Table" with the same name. All formulas are not working

Comment: have you verified the actual contents of the formulas in question after the delete happens?  Have you tried manually performing these steps to verify them?

Comment: I'm not  sure what you mean. Actual content of fromulas: =#ADR!B3+#ADR!C3
It should be =Sheet1!B3+Sheet1!C3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will have to do is, in the sheet that contains the formulas, firstly convert them away from formulas (this will stop Excel from creating errors in your formulas when you delete the sheet that thse formulas are referencing).

So, for example, do a Find/Replace and replace "=" with, for example "#" (or any other character or set of characters you're sure you're not using in that sheet).
Thsi will stop the formula from creating an errored reference.

Then delete the sheet, add in the new sheet

Then re-replace the values in your formula sheet back from "#" to "=".

So long as your new sheet has the same name as the old sheet, you should be good to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The idea is not bad. I'm only not sure how long does it take to replace all characters in all cells. If not much then great.

Comment: It's actually extremely fast - especially if you turn off calculation before you do the replace