# How to persist Excel References in formulas across worksheets where the worksheet is blank?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Is it possible in Excel to create a template with formula to other named empty sheets such that the references to the cells always remain and don't end up like this?

```
='Data'!#REF!
```

I am using python, pandas and openpyxl to populate multiple named worksheets with various pandas dataframes.  The 1st, 2nd and 3rd sheets are templates with references to the other worksheets.

**Why is this required :** If I have data in the template of say 10 rows and write a dataframe of 5 rows the remaining 5 existing rows remain.

It might be possible to clear the target sheet before the to_excel but I think this may force the links to break.

I've looked at this [How to preserve a formula's reference to a worksheet when the worksheet is deleted and replaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070930/how-to-preserve-a-formulas-reference-to-a-worksheet-when-the-worksheet-is-delet) but it seems quite tedious to have to create another indirect reference.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved using Named Ranges.